# gain control by wxSlider

Tags: c++, slider, wxwidgets

I am using wxSlider to adjust gain in my Windows C++ application.
Bind() function code:

```
sliderAmp->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_SLIDER_UPDATED, wxScrollEventHandler(App::OnSliderAmpChanged), this);
```

With such an implementation, the effect of "bounce" of values appears, i.e. multiple identical values may appear.

How to change the code so that the gain control is more reasonable?

Comment: are you sure that this is the bind call you are using? You should pass a reference to the handler and not handler itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `wxEVT_COMMAND_SLIDER_UPDATED` is an alias of `wxEVT_SLIDER`, and in the latest versions only the latter remained documented.

I think you need to handle only `wxEVT_SCROLL_CHANGED`. Unfortunately that is documented to be *MSW only*.

For non-MSW, you might get away with handling `wxEVT_SCROLL_THUMBRELEASE`. In case you want keyboard support you might need to add handling of other events. See [wxSlider Class Reference](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_slider.html) too.

Comment: Yes, wxEVT_SCROLL_CHANGED definitely works better! It only uses the last value of the slider, i.e. when I release the mouse.
Thank you!